# Address not found preventing model save | gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I was trying to save a new object to my DB and realized that gmaps4rails was preventing the save because the address was not being found by the geocoder:

In my log:

```
The address you passed seems invalid, status was: ZERO_RESULTS.
```

Is there a way to save the object without setting lat/lng when this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is [in the wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization):

```
 acts_as_gmappable validation: false
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to this fixed the same issue for me

```
  #gmaps for rails
  acts_as_gmappable :validation => false
```